# How to calculate percentage increase from previous row/day after complex Group By?

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a table IntradayPrices1Minute where I store **1 minute** timeframe open, high, low and close prices for stocks:

```
  CREATE TABLE `IntradayPrices1Minute` (
  `ticker` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `volume` mediumint(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `open` decimal(8,4) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `high` decimal(8,4) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `low` decimal(8,4) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `close` decimal(8,4) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`datetime`,`ticker`),
  UNIQUE KEY `indxTickerDatetime` (`ticker`,`datetime`) USING BTREE
)
```

I have successfully build a query where I can calculate the **daily** open, high, low and close prices for those stocks. This is the query:

```
SELECT 
    ticker,
    DATE(datetime) AS 'Date',
    SUBSTRING_INDEX( GROUP_CONCAT(CAST(open AS CHAR) ORDER BY datetime), ',', 1 ) as 'Daily Open',
    max(GREATEST(open, high, low, close)) AS 'Daily High',
    min(LEAST(open, high, low, close)) AS 'Daily Low',
    SUBSTRING_INDEX( GROUP_CONCAT(CAST(close AS CHAR) ORDER BY datetime DESC), ',', 1 ) as 'Daily Close'

FROM 
    IntradayPrices1Minute

GROUP BY
    ticker, date(datetime)
```

and this is part of the results that this query successfully returns:

```
ticker  Date        Open    High    Low     Close
----    ----------  ------  ------  ------  ------ 
AAAE    2012-11-26  0.0100  0.0100  0.0100  0.0100
AAAE    2012-11-27  0.0130  0.0140  0.0083  0.0140
AAAE    2012-11-28  0.0140  0.0175  0.0140  0.0165
AAAE    2012-11-29  0.0175  0.0175  0.0137  0.0137
AAMRQ   2012-11-26  0.4411  0.5300  0.4411  0.5290
AAMRQ   2012-11-27  0.5100  0.5110  0.4610  0.4950
AAMRQ   2012-11-28  0.4820  0.4900  0.4300  0.4640
AAMRQ   2012-11-29  0.4505  0.4590  0.4411  0.4590
AAMRQ   2012-11-30  0.4500  0.4570  0.4455  0.4568
```

Now the problem is: I want to return a seventh column in the query that calculates for each day the percentage increase/decrease between its close price and the previous day close price.

I have seen similar questions asked on StackOverflow but for situations in which the daily prices are already in a table. I think it is specially complex in my case because the daily prices are obtained at query time after several grouping calculations.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.
Many Thanks.
Boga

Comment: What are the meanings of the `open`, `high`, `low` and `close` columns in your table?  For example, why would an entry half-way through the day have a `close` value?  Would the `open` value be the same for every entry in the day?  Would the `high` and `low` values be moving throughout the day?  Why don't you just have a single `price` column for that moment in time?  Or perhaps `bid` and `ask` columns?  Indeed, what does `volume` hold: the volume traded since the last record?  I suspect you ought to spend some time thinking a little more about your schema.

Comment: Hi eggyval and thanks for answering. IntradayPrices1Minute stores the price changes in the **1 minute** timeframe. So for each stock, I have a row for each minute where there was at least 1 trade. The price that stock had when that minute started is the `open` price. The price it had when that minute ended is the `close` price. The `volume` column is the number of shares traded during that minute, etc... From those 1 minute price changes I created the query to get the `open`, `low`, `high`, and `close` for the **1 day** timeframe.Hope you understand my question better now. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please take a look at this reference: [SQLFIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ff809/9)

So your current table with OHLC is used to derive the px_change, px_pct :)
Results have been `rounded` to show 4 decimal points in change as well as percentage. 
**Null is used to show no price change/pct as null is a better representation of no price change 
than having a zero price change ;)**

Query:

```
select ticker, date_format(date,'%m-%d-%Y') as date, open, high,low,close,
pxchange,concat(round(pxpct*100,4),'%') pxpct
from (select case when ticker <> @pxticker 
        then @pxclose := null end, p.*, (close-@pxclose) as pxchange,
    (close-@pxclose)/@pxclose as pxpct, (@pxclose := close),
    (@pxticker := ticker) from pricing p
cross join
    (select @pxclose := null, @pxticker := ticker
     from pricing 
     order by ticker, date limit 1)  as a
  order by ticker, date ) as b
order by ticker, date asc
```

Resutls:

```
TICKER  DATE        OPEN    HIGH    LOW     CLOSE   PXCHANGE  PXPCT
AAAE    11-26-2012  0.01    0.01    0.01    0.01    (null)    (null)
AAAE    11-27-2012  0.013   0.014   0.0083  0.014   0.004     40.0000%
AAAE    11-28-2012  0.014   0.0175  0.014   0.0165  0.0025    17.8571%
AAAE    11-29-2012  0.0175  0.0175  0.0137  0.0137  -0.0028   -16.9697%
AAMRQ   11-26-2012  0.4411  0.53    0.4411  0.529   (null)    (null)
AAMRQ   11-27-2012  0.51    0.511   0.461   0.495   -0.034    -6.4272%
AAMRQ   11-28-2012  0.482   0.49    0.43    0.464   -0.031    -6.2626%
AAMRQ   11-29-2012  0.4505  0.459   0.4411  0.459   -0.005    -1.0776%
AAMRQ   11-30-2012  0.45    0.457   0.4455  0.4568  -0.0022   -0.4793%
```

** UPDATED WITH A PICTURE TO SHOW THE PARENTHESIS AS PER OP'S REQUEST IN COMMENTS ** :)

[image]

Comment: Thank you `bonCodigo` for answering. However, your query is designed to be aplied directly to a table that already holds the OHLC prices, but remember I need to calculate daily percent price changes from my query results. The reason is that I have the 1 minute OHLC prices in the table, while the daily OHLC prices I calculate them in the query. Maybe I wasn´t clear enough explaining the type of data I store in the `IntradayPrices1Minute` table. Please see the comment I left to user eggyal at the top of the comments. Cheers and thank you :-)

Comment: Actually... your approach works great for me. Inspired in part by Olaf´s answer, I have created a view with my query to get have ready the daily OHLC values from the 1 minute OHLC prices table, and I have tried your suggested query(with minor editing) against that view, and the output is exaclty what I need. Thanks a million!

Comment: Excellent! Will you be happy to update your question with final answer? :) and mark the correct asnwers here, so qustion is solved for the system records :D

Comment: Sure I will! But excuse me because this was my first question, so I don´t know what is the procedure/etiquette for updating question with final answer nor how to mark the correct answers. Is there some wiki or faq that explains this? thanks

Comment: What I meant was to update your question by *appending* your correct answer with a heading --> my final answer, so anyone can refer to that as well :) You may keep the original text as it is. And append the answer. So you are not changing your original question and info.

Comment: I figured out the tick to mark the answers as correct, but the appending of the correct answer I am a bit unsure. Would it be too much to ask for you to point me to an example of a question where the answer has been appended to help me understand? thanks :-)

Comment: You may vote up Olaf as well, since he has helped you out greatly :) Append is pretty straightforward, you add a heading below your entire text in the question, and add your final answer. Apology I am unable to find an example for you at this moment.

Comment: Would you mind explaining a bit the concepts involved in your query and why it seems to be so fast/efficient? I am trying to understand it so I can maybe apply its concepts to other queries. Plus I am confused by your use of right parenthesis `)` in the join. It´s probably my inexperience :-)

Comment: sorry for the rather late reply. I broke down the query here for you to understand. Two main things here, 1. this query works for a ticker even dates are not consecutive 2. when a new stock ticker is found, it resets the previous day price to null to make sure no px_chg is calculated. Can you update your question and point me to the right `)` parenthesis you are talking about. BTW how is the API going? ;) you are downloading data from BBG?

Comment: Hi. I have trouble understanding the syntax in the join because it seems like you close `)` at `date ) as b` without having opened with `(` first? BTW: I download data from Google Finance.

Comment: I am sorry, but where/what did you update with a pic? I cannot find anything else apart from your original answer at the top with the link to SQL Fiddle and your query, and then your comments(and mine). What am I´m missing? thanks!

Comment: One question about your query. The value PXPCT in your query calculate s the percent/increase in price between the close of that day and the close of **the previous trading day**, right?(the previous date for which there is price data). So for mondays it will show the percent increase/decrease from friday´s close.... and in case that for example tuesday was a holiday, so there was no price data that day, on wednesday it will show the PCXCHANGE from monday´s close, right?

Comment: What you are saying is right as long as your input data is processed accordingly :) Because query doesn't have any means to know what holiday calendar of your country/business follows. So when you feed the pricing data, that has to comply accordingly. What query does is picking out today/previous day data. E.g. Friday was a holiday - exchange closed. So no price. In that case you have no row for Friday, but last trading day: Thursday. Query will take Thursday in that case. If you are referring about making query to be smart enough to pic calendar holidays --> then that's something new to talk.

Comment: thanks. you just confirmed that your query does what I wanted ;-)

Comment: To be very sure, you can try it with sample data with different dates that you want to test. And see if query results come along as expected :) That's the only way to confirm. Specially when money involved ;)

Answer (score 1):

`high` should already contain the greatest and `low` should already contain the least value.

First, I'd rewrite your select and create it as a view as

```
create view daily_prices as
SELECT 
    ticker,
    DATE(datetime) AS 'Date',
    SUBSTRING_INDEX( GROUP_CONCAT(CAST(open AS CHAR) ORDER BY datetime), ',', 1 ) as 'Daily Open',
    max(high) AS 'Daily High',
    min(low) AS 'Daily Low',
    SUBSTRING_INDEX( GROUP_CONCAT(CAST(close AS CHAR) ORDER BY datetime DESC), ',', 1 ) as 'Daily Close'
FROM 
    IntradayPrices1Minute
GROUP BY
    ticker, date(datetime)
```

then you can do a self join

```
select d1.*, d1.`daily close` / d2.`daily close` - 1 as `percent change`
from daily_prices d1
join daily_prices d2 on d1.ticker = d2.ticker and d1.`date` = adddate(d2.`date`, 1)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f0086/3/0)

Comment: Thank you Olaf. I was obsessed with trying to do it in only 1 query. I  am not very experienced and not familiar with views. Does it have any storage or spedd implications to do it this way? Thank you!

Comment: Also, after trying your approach, this is part of the results I get:    ´   AAAE 2012-11-27 0.0130 0.0140 0.0083 0.0140 0.3999999999999999
AAAE 2012-11-28 0.0140 0.0175 0.0140 0.0165 0.1785714285714286
AAAE 2012-11-29 0.0175 0.0175 0.0137 0.0137 -0.16969696969696968

Comment: I am very sorry for the mess in my comments. I am just starting today in Stackoverflow so everything is new to me. Olaf: I am trying to test your suggested approach however I see that you have percent changes in the first rows of the groups(i.e: 0.4 for November, 27 2012 for stock AAAE). But this is wrong, because this is the first day that I have data, so there is no previous day, so there should not be any percentage increase/decrease :-(

Comment: @dodecafonico The first day is 2012-11-26, which is not listed. If you want to see this one as well, you need to do a left join.

Comment: @dodecafonico I created the view to simplify the select. You can get the same result with using two subqueries, of course.

Comment: Thank you Olaf. I have tried user Peladao´s approach, using your create view suggestion and his approach gives the results in 6 seconds(will be less when once I use some filter), but your query took more than 200 seconds(The IntradayPrices1Minute currently holds just 5 days of data and it has already 500000 records!). But thanks a million for sharing your knowledge with me!

Comment: sorry I meant I used bonCodigo´s approach