# Is it possible to JOIN the results of a view with the results of a query in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

So I have this wonderful query working thanks to user bonCodigo [in a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13671230/how-to-calculate-percentage-increase-from-previous-row-day-after-complex-group-b) he answered to me:

```
SELECT 
    ticker, 
    `Date` as date, 
    `Daily Open`, 
    `Daily High`,
    `Daily Low`,
    `Daily Close`,
    concat(round(pxpct*100,2),'%') `Percent change`

FROM 
    (select case when ticker <> @pxticker then @pxclose := null end, 
    p.*, 
    (`Daily Close`-@pxclose) as pxchange,
    (`Daily Close`-@pxclose)/@pxclose as pxpct, 
    (@pxclose := `Daily Close`),
    (@pxticker := ticker) from viewDailyOHLCPrices p
JOIN
    (select @pxclose := null, @pxticker := ticker from viewDailyOHLCPrices order by     ticker, date limit 1)  as a
    order by ticker, date ) as b
order by ticker, date asc
```

which returns me results like this:

```
TICKER  DATE        OPEN    HIGH    LOW     CLOSE   PXCHANGE  PXPCT
AAAE    11-26-2012  0.01    0.01    0.01    0.01    (null)    (null)
AAAE    11-27-2012  0.013   0.014   0.0083  0.014   0.004     40.0000%
AAAE    11-28-2012  0.014   0.0175  0.014   0.0165  0.0025    17.8571%
AAAE    11-29-2012  0.0175  0.0175  0.0137  0.0137  -0.0028   -16.9697%
AAMRQ   11-26-2012  0.4411  0.53    0.4411  0.529   (null)    (null)
AAMRQ   11-27-2012  0.51    0.511   0.461   0.495   -0.034    -6.4272%
AAMRQ   11-28-2012  0.482   0.49    0.43    0.464   -0.031    -6.2626%
AAMRQ   11-29-2012  0.4505  0.459   0.4411  0.459   -0.005    -1.0776%
AAMRQ   11-30-2012  0.45    0.457   0.4455  0.4568  -0.0022   -0.4793%
```

Now I have a view, let´s call it for simplicity `myview` and let´s say that it has fields: `date, ticker, v1, v2`

Is there a way that I can join the results from view1 with the results of the query above so I end up with results like this?

```
DATE          TICKER    v1    v2    DATE        OPEN    HIGH    LOW     CLOSE   PXCHANGE  PXPCT
11-25-2012    AAAE      117   287   11-26-2012  0.01    0.01    0.01    0.01    (null)    (null)
11-26-2012    AAAE      339   159   11-27-2012  0.013   0.014   0.0083  0.014   0.004     40.0000%
11-27-2012    AAAE      219   937   11-28-2012  0.014   0.0175  0.014   0.0165  0.0025    17.8571%
11-28-2012    AAAE      821   403   11-29-2012  0.0175  0.0175  0.0137  0.0137  -0.0028   -16.9697%
11-25-2012    AAMRQ     263   721   11-26-2012  0.4411  0.53    0.4411  0.529   (null)    (null)
11-26-2012    AAMRQ     173   932   11-27-2012  0.51    0.511   0.461   0.495   -0.034    -6.4272%
11-27-2012    AAMRQ     218   364   11-28-2012  0.482   0.49    0.43    0.464   -0.031    -6.2626%
11-28-2012    AAMRQ     234   844   11-29-2012  0.4505  0.459   0.4411  0.459   -0.005    -1.0776%
11-29-2012    AAMRQ     821   472   11-30-2012  0.45    0.457   0.4455  0.4568  -0.0022   -0.4793%
```

As you might see, I would like to join `myview` and the query by the `ticker` and the `date` fields (**the following trading day´s date** in case of the second date column). This is important because `myview` queries from a table where I have data for every single day including saturdays and sundays, but the view `viewDailyOHLCPrices` queries a table where I have data only for open trading days(usually Mon-Fri...but no data on saturdays and sundays nor when a weekday holiday).
So the second date column must be the next trading day(the next day for which there is data in the `viewDailyOHLCPrices` view).

So in the example results that I hardcoded, in the first row, I do want the values `v1` & `v2` for `11-25-2012`(sunday), the `open`, `high`, `low`, `close` prices for `11-26-2012`(monday), and the price change between `11-26-2012`(monday) and `11-23-2012`(friday)... and so on.

The query I posted at the beginning already handles the percent increase/decrease(PXPT) from one day, to the previous day fro which there is price data(for that `ticker`)

(in this case the first row has PXPCT as ´(null)´ just because I don´t have data from before ´11-25-2012´)

I know that I can JOIN 2 or more tables, or 2 or more views, but I am not sure if you can JOIN a view and a query(like in my question).

I really hope that I haven´t made my question overcomplicated or messy. Please don´t hesitate to ask for any clarification you might need ;-)

Thank you!,
boga.

Comment: Yes its possible to join a view and table.
Please note view is nothing but a select query.
you use view and your o/p of the query in join statements.

Comment: ok, thanks for replying, but how would I do that in the case I described, in which I have a view and a relatevely complex query with variables, joins, aggregate functions, etc... already in it?

Comment: please find the sample here it will be like 
select <required columns> from view join (complex query) on (values to be joined)

Comment: oh, I feel embarassed. It was that simple! How could I have missed that? In the MySQL doc of JOIN I didn´t see any reference to joining with a query, nor googling. So it is as simple as that, ok. Thank you very much :-)